# Can I speed up the Windows 8 lock screen animation?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, lock-screen

Problem: When I hit a key to slide the lock screen image up, it takes a second until the password field is in focus. I have to wait a second before I'm able to start typing my password.

I've done a bit of research and have found a way to DISABLE the Windows 8 lock screen, which would technically solve my initial problem. However, I still want to keep the lock screen image.

So I was wondering if there is a way to speed up the animation (preferably instantaneous) when the image slides up to reveal and focus on the password field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a setting to remove the animation, hidden in the Metro Settings.

In the start menu, type "animations", select **Turn Windows animations on or off** under PC Settings, and switch the slider off for **Play animations in Windows**.

I'm not sure what else this would affect, but now my lock screen image goes away instantaneously and I can type my password without delay.

Edit: The same setting is also under the classic **Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Make the computer easier to see**. At the bottom of the page, check **Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)**.

Answer (score 1):

There are settings that control the animations you see in Windows.  Open "System" and select "Settings..." under the Performance section of the Advanced tab.

I chose the "Adjust for best performance" and it stopped the lock screen from sliding.  I don't know exactly which of the checkboxes did it - if you find out, please comment.  Nothing specifically says lockscreen, so whichever one it is, you'll probably end up having an effect on some other areas of Windows.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Kevin Lau's answer is much cleaner, I'm actually going to upvote his.

Comment: This settings page was the first thing I thought of, but there are several settings which help with readability that I didn't want to mess with. I didn't actually expect it to affect the lock screen though, nice find.

Answer (score 1):

The lock screen animation cannot be disabled on its own, it's consolidated within the setting **Animate controls and elements inside windows** found underneath **Performance Options**.

There are a couple of ways to open this specific window:

1. <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type in "*SystemPropertiesPerformance*" and click on <kbd>OK</kbd>.
2. *Right Click* Start > System > Advanced system settings > Performance.

Finally, remove the check mark from the previously mentioned setting.

> Going into the registry doesn't help either, the animation is
>   consolidated like before. Change the key by going to
>   "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask", then
>   modify the 5th value (12 = On, 10 = Off).